# Booking reservations API for calender

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is there any calender API to check the availability and reserve the particular Timings. we are basically looking to develop an application which will check the availability of the doctor timings from his calender for the patients to book an appointment. Is there any calender API which meets this use case?

Comment: You can use google calendar API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ for your use case. Doctor's calendar should be shared to  your application so that your application can access the doctor calendar events.

Comment: Ok. Can you suggest which api shall we use and provide any sample example / code for reference ?